# Computer freezes unexpectedly, can't figure out the cause

Tags: windows, freeze

My operating system is Windows 7 Professional 32-Bit on a 64 bit AMD processor with 4 GB RAM.

The symptoms are:

- The mouse movements are extremely delayed (I move the mouse, the pointer moves seconds later)
- Keyboard pressed are ignored or repeated (I press a key once and 5 of that letter is registered)
- The network gets disconnected
- Any audio playing starts skipping

It happens sporadically. The processor temperature is normal. Once I restart my computer it boots into windows normally and everything works normally again. I can continue to use the computer for hours or days before it happens again. I cannot figure out how to replicate it; it happens at random times...

Comment: Not enough information (I know, that's a killer thing to say). Is the machine overheating? Are you able to get into Safe Mode and replicate the problem? If it doesn't present in Safe Mode, it could be something malware-related (but that's a guess), or hardware driver.

Comment: I have this exact same problem.  Often happens when I'm watching a video, but not all the time.  Only difference I see is that my network doesn't get disconnected but I'm also on a hardline.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like some process is consuming too many resources.  Ctrl-alt-del into Task Manager and look for processes that are hovering at high percentages.  Use Google to find out what applications the processes belong to and you can do further troubleshooting from there.

[Sysinternal's Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) is a bit better for this task, so if you can manage to download that from another system and run it from a USB drive, try that.

Answer (score 1):

This could be one of so many different problems...

The mere fact it happens fairly sporadically and sometime after a few days of use leads me to believe it could be a memory fault. I have a machine with 4GB RAM in it which sometimes has the same set of issues. I discovered that it was always happening when the memory was close to full... if I remove the last bank of ram it works fine.

That is a guess however; not a definitive answer.  You could narrow it down by running a memory monitor then using something to fill up the memory to see if it the system always 'conks out' at the same fill point?

Comment: Would running memtest find this type of RAM issue?

Comment: Yeah, looks like memtest should do the job of checking for faulty sticks.  Give it a go, I've not tested it that way recently,.. my tests were more of a casual noticing that it was always at the same memory load point when it crashed out on me.

Comment: I have this exact same issue.  My ram was my first guess so I ran memtest and was 100% error free.